# Youtube does not working like usual in my laptop

Tags: html, browser, youtube

I'm just reformatted my laptop. I opened Youtube in my browser and Youtube does not work as normal. I did a `inspect element` there and some error is found there mostly regarding to some script that's unable to be loaded.

I do request some help here.

[image]

Comment: please take a look on the link. It will display the picture of my youtube current condition

Comment: This is not a `Flash` issue and this is not even a **programming** Question. Try asking this at [**`SuperUser.com`**](http://www.superuser.com). While you wait for an answer there try to get helpful info (_ie:_ Does the site work fine in a different browser? What happens when you clear cache/cookies? Does your internet settings disable all image loading or are images loading fine for other sites?).